# Highcharts - Toggle between different data with dropdown box

Tags: meteor, highcharts

The title of the question is a bit vague because its difficult to explain so please bear with me.

First off i'm using Meteor to build my application and the data is being fetched from MongoDB.

My MongoDB data looks like this:

[image: Data]

And currently I have my highcharts large tree map pointing just to the 'BILL' category of the data. It works fine and renders the chart. The code for my chart looks like this (Unfortunately I cannot configure it to be a running working version) :

```js
Template.chart.onCreated(function chartOnCreated() {
  this.subscribe('someData');
});

Template.chart.onRendered(function chartOnRendered() {
  this.autorun(() => {
    if (this.subscriptionsReady()) {
      const data = MyCollection.findOne({_id: "HaQpg4pxhkrGhJPsX"}).BILL;
      var points = [],
        categoryPoints,
        categoryVal,
        categoryI = 0,
        issueTypePoints,
        issueTypeI,
        currencyPoints,
        currencyI,
        periodPoints,
        periodI,
        ECHoldingPoints,
        ECHoldingI,
        ECConcentrationPoints,
        ECConcentrationI,
        ECBPoints,
        ECBI,
        issueCountryPoints,
        issueCountryI,
        issueNamePoints,
        issueNameI,
        ISINPoints,
        ISINI,
        zeroI,
        zeroPoints,
        category,
        issueType,
        currency,
        period,
        ECHolding,
        ECConcentration,
        ECB,
        issueCountry,
        IssueName,
        ISIN,
        zero,
        mil,
        causeMil,
        causeMilI;

      for (category in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(category)) {
          categoryVal = 0;

          categoryPoints = {
            id: 'id_' + categoryI,
            name: category,
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[categoryI]
          };

          issueTypeI = 0;
          for (issueType in data[category]) {
            if (data[category].hasOwnProperty(issueType)) {

              issueTypePoints = {
                id: categoryPoints.id + '_' + issueTypeI,
                name: issueType,
                parent: categoryPoints.id,
              };
              points.push(issueTypePoints);

              currencyI = 0;
              for (currency in data[category][issueType]) {
                if (data[category][issueType].hasOwnProperty(currency)) {

                  currencyPoints = {
                    id: issueTypePoints.id + '_' + currencyI,
                    name: currency,
                    parent: issueTypePoints.id
                  };
                  points.push(currencyPoints);

                  periodI = 0;
                  for (period in data[category][issueType][currency]) {
                    if (data[category][issueType][currency].hasOwnProperty(period)) {

                      periodPoints = {
                        id: currencyPoints.id + '_' + periodI,
                        name: period,
                        parent: currencyPoints.id,
                      };
                      points.push(periodPoints);

                      ECHoldingI = 0;
                      for (ECHolding in data[category][issueType][currency][period]) {
                        if (data[category][issueType][currency][period].hasOwnProperty(ECHolding)) {

                          ECHoldingPoints = {
                            id: periodPoints.id + '_' + ECHoldingI,
                            name: ECHolding,
                            parent: periodPoints.id,
                          };
                          points.push(ECHoldingPoints);

                          ECConcentrationI = 0;
                          for (ECConcentration in data[category][issueType][currency][period][ECHolding]) {
                            if (data[category][issueType][currency][period][ECHolding].hasOwnProperty(ECConcentration)) {

                              ECConcentrationPoints = {
                                id: ECHoldingPoints.id + '_' + ECConcentrationI,
                                name: ECConcentration,
                                parent: ECHoldingPoints.id,
                              };
                              points.push(ECConcentrationPoints);

                              ECBI = 0;
                              for (ECB in data[category][issueType][currency][period][ECHolding][ECConcentration]) {
                                if (data[category][issueType][currency][period][ECHolding][ECConcentration].hasOwnProperty(ECB)) {

                                  ECBPoints = {
                                    id: ECConcentrationPoints.id + '_' + ECBI,
                                    name: ECB,
                                    parent: ECConcentrationPoints.id,
                                  };
                                  points.push(ECBPoints);

                                  issueCountryI = 0;
                                  for (issueCountry in data[category][issueType][currency][period][ECHolding][ECConcentration][ECB]) {
                                    if (data[category][issueType][currency][period][ECHolding][ECConcentration][ECB].hasOwnProperty(issueCountry)) {

                                      issueCountryPoints = {
                                        id: ECBPoints.id + '_' + issueCountryI,
                                        name: issueCountry,
                                        parent: ECBPoints.id,
                                      };
                                      points.push(issueCountryPoints);

                                      issueNameI = 0;
                                      for (issueName in data[category][issueType][currency][period][ECHolding][ECConcentration][ECB][issueCountry]) {
                                        if (data[category][issueType][currency][period][ECHolding][ECConcentration][ECB][issueCountry].hasOwnProperty(issueName)) {

                                          issueNamePoints = {
                                            id: issueCountryPoints.id + '_' + issueNameI,
                                            name: issueName,
                                            parent: issueCountryPoints.id,
                                          };
                                          points.push(issueNamePoints);

                                          ISINI = 0;
                                          for (ISIN in data[category][issueType][currency][period][ECHolding][ECConcentration][ECB][issueCountry][issueName]) {
                                            if (data[category][issueType][currency][period][ECHolding][ECConcentration][ECB][issueCountry][issueName].hasOwnProperty(ISIN)) {

                                              ISINPoints = {
                                                id: issueNamePoints.id + '_' + ISINI,
                                                name: ISIN,
                                                parent: issueNamePoints.id,
                                              };
                                              points.push(ISINPoints);

                                                  causeMilI = 0;
                                                  for (mil in data[category][issueType][currency][period][ECHolding][ECConcentration][ECB][issueCountry][issueName][ISIN]) {
                                                    if (data[category][issueType][currency][period][ECHolding][ECConcentration][ECB][issueCountry][issueName][ISIN].hasOwnProperty(mil)) {

                                                      causeMil = {
                                                        id: ISINPoints.id + '_' + causeMilI,
                                                        name: mil,
                                                        parent: ISINPoints.id,
                                                        value: Math.round(+data[category][issueType][currency][period][ECHolding][ECConcentration][ECB][issueCountry][issueName][ISIN][mil])
                                                      };
                                                      categoryVal += causeMil.value;
                                                      points.push(causeMil);
                                                      causeMilI = causeMilI + 1;
                                                    }
                                                  }

                                              ISINPoints = ISINPoints + 1;
                                            }
                                          }
                                          issueNameI = issueNameI + 1;
                                        }
                                      }
                                      issueCountryI = issueCountryI + 1;
                                    }
                                  }
                                  ECBI = ECBI + 1;
                                }
                              }
                              ECConcentrationI = ECConcentrationI + 1;
                            }
                          }
                          ECHoldingI = ECHoldingI + 1;
                        }
                      }
                      periodI = periodI + 1;
                    }
                  }
                  currencyI = currencyI + 1;
                }
              }
              issueTypeI = issueTypeI + 1;
            }
          }
          categoryPoints.value = Math.round(categoryVal / issueTypeI);
          points.push(categoryPoints);
          categoryI = categoryI + 1;
        }
      }
      Highcharts.chart('chart', {
        credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            turboThreshold: 0,
            boostThreshold: 0
          }
        },
        series: [{
          type: 'treemap',
          layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
          allowDrillToNode: true,
          animationLimit: 1000,
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
          },
          levelIsConstant: false,
          levels: [{
            level: 1,
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
            },
            borderWidth: 3
          }],
          data: points
        }],
        title: {
          text: ''
        },
      },
    );
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<template name="chart">
  <div id="chart" style="width: 450px; height: 260px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
</template>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/GeorgeBT/cg8mw0ue/) is a link to a JSFiddle of the chart too (But again this is not a working version just the code)

What I would like to have is a toggle drop down list containing 'BILL' 'BOND' 'MTN' and 'NOTE' and when the user selects an option the string here:

```
const data = MyCollection.findOne({_id: "HaQpg4pxhkrGhJPsX"}). <USERS SELECTION>;
```

The USERS SELECTION will be updated with their choice - For example .BILL - and the chart will render that data.

Can anybody help with how I would do that?

Many thanks,

G

Comment: You should try something like `const data = MyCollection.findOne({_id: "HaQpg4pxhkrGhJPsX"})[<USERS SELECTION>];`

Comment: Thank you - I shall give this a try

Comment: I'm almost sure it works, i already used it many times. What is the error when you type: const data = MyCollection.findOne({_id: "HaQpg4pxhkrGhJPsX"})["BILL"]; ?

Comment: Apologies Benjamin. When testing I must have still been including the . between `({_id: "HaQpg4pxhkrGhJPsX"})` and `[<USERS SELECTION>];`. Your solution has worked for me now I removed the . Thank you

Comment: No problem, I am going to write an answer to close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `const data = MyCollection.findOne({_id: "HaQpg4pxhkrGhJPsX"})["<USERS SELECTION>"];`

In javascript, you can access to a value of a certain JSON object field by many ways:

```
var obj = { key : 'value' }
var lookup = 'key'

console.log( obj.lookup ) //undefined
console.log( obj.key ) //value
console.log( obj[lookup] ) //value
```